# React+redux app with css (media query based css ) not working css properties on apache server

Tags: css, reactjs

React+redux app with css (media query based css ) working css properties on npm server fine when i start the server by npm start . but after deployed the react app on apache which has css properties not working . i mean media query css not working on apache server . is apache server dont support media query

Comment: Media queries are a browser feature and shouldn't be affected at all by your server. You should check to make sure that your stylesheet is being served correctly.

Comment: its working with npm server means probably  problem may cause by apache server right

Comment: No its not the case, its not affected by apache/npm you should really check your media queries

Comment: its working now .. the problem is i  deployed in tomcat server since its looking for absolute path. but if  deploy on apache server  am not getting this issue . only on tomcat has this isssue . there for   if we deploy on apache we should have absolute path . in case of apache  no need of absolute path